# Spring Data Hibernate Idenity strategy not generating values from 1, can someone explain me how this works?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to insert a record from my spring application, but whenever I try to insert a new record, ID generated is 6 digit value even if there are no records present in the database. Can someone help me on why is it working this way.

My Entity class code is:

```
    @Entity
    public class Customer {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer customerId; ... rest of code
```

Database table had one record previously and when I added a new record, generated value was as shown.(P.s. my database had records previously which I deleted and added a new record(rohan) manually using mysql and when another record was added, this value was generated.)

[mysql database snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Koi67.png)

Comment: Try resetting the value.
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

Comment: By manually resetting the value, It works fine. But my requirement is that new record generated must use previously used value + 1.

Comment: Yes that is what is expected post reset, is it still same ?

Comment: Post reset it works fine, thanks.

Comment: Is there any way in hibernate using which I can use the given alter statement in Java application itself? apart from using JDBC to run query.

Comment: This is one time required, so no need to run it in java application.